# Проектирование таблиц для хранения больших объемов статистики

Tags: база-данных, sql

В игре хоккеисты имеют статистику по сезонам по нескольким параметрам: голы, передачи, броски и т.д. Один хоккеист в среднем имеет 10-15 - летнюю игровую карьеру, в соответствии с игрой сезон длится ~ 2 месяца, т.е. карьера игрока длится порядка 20-30 месяцев. После этого вся информация об игроке удаляется из базы. На данный момент игроков порядка 75 тысяч.

Как организовать хранение статистики в базе данных?

Answer (score 4):

Самое легкое что пришло в голову - разбить всю хранимую информацию (голы, броски и тд) в таблицах по годам. И сделать одну таблицу, которая будет содержать имена таблиц и соответствующие им временные отрезки.

Продолжая мысль - в зависимости от того какие результаты нужно получать на основании статистики, их также можно посчитать за закрытый период и уже хранить, а не считать каждый раз.

Answer (score 1):

По идее, структура БД должна быть такой, чтобы *чемпионаты*, *сезоны*, *игры*, *игроки* и *статистика по игрокам* были бы в отдельных таблицах. В таблице со статистикой (наряду с самым главным -- параметрами) должна быть **связь** внешним ключом с таблицами игр и игроков, т.к. именно по параметрам статистики игрока в конкретной игре строится и статистика за игру, и в сезоне, и в чемпионате.

Т.е. на мой взгляд, нет ничего плохого в хранении всей статистики в разрезе игроков в одной таблице.

Comment: Да. Я бы ещё порекомендовал для таблицы статистики сделать уникальный ключ с автоинкрементом и кластерным индексом, а также обычные индексы по всем ключам. Для оптимизации запросов можно ещё прибегнуть к некоторой денормализации, втащив в таблицу статистики данные, которые можно было бы получить подзапросами. Но это должны быть только те данные, которые реально требуется отобразить пользователю.

Answer (score 0):

Данные об игроках, и результатах игры как я понял хранятся достаточно долго, поэтому предлагаю ниже приложенный вариант. Создать таблицы. Данные о результатах игроков хранить в таблице "Результат игры". Обновление таблицы средствами приложения[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]